# Would this question on steganographic protocol design be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, migration

A question about [steganographic protocol design](https://serverfault.com/q/766358/214507) was asked on Server Fault. It appears to be off-topic on Server Fault. To me security.stackexchange.com seems like the most obvious site to migrate it to. Would it be on-topic here?

Comment: I assume you mean "steganography", and not "shorthand"?

Comment: @AviD Sure. I just copied the word from the original question without noticing the mistake in the original.

Answer (score 1):

Kasperd - as it stands, the question would not be suitable on any SE site. The current structure has multiple questions, some unrelated and confusing information, and a title that muddies the water further.

If you could clarify it down to one question, as per our [ask] page, you could ask it here.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. I saw it in the review queue and tried to figure out which site it would be suitable for.

Comment: Thanks kasperd - I've popped this comment over there.